# Why ActiveModel is not returning the attribute value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 3.0.10

```
class Friend
  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :email

  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::AttributeMethods
  define_attribute_methods [:first_name, :last_name, :email]
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  def persisted?; false; end
end


> Friend.new(:first_name => 'John').first_name
 => nil
```

What do I need to do to retrieve the first_name.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is different in Rails 3.0.10, but doesn't your class have to extend the Active Record Base? I.e, `class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base`

Comment: That's the point. It works with a model backed by a table but I do not have  a table and I am looking for this feature.

Comment: What we're saying is that assigning properties from a hash is in ActiveRecord::Base. You'd either need to extend ActiveRecord::Base, or implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you need an initializer?

```
def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
        send("#{name}=", value)
    end
end
```

Comment: There's a RailsCast on the subject : http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model

Answer (score 0):

The mass assignment stuff comes from [ActiveRecord::Base](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L1710), no?